# How to delete redundant folder?

Tags: windows-7

I do a lot of archive extraction per day.

Archives come in two types:

- archive / folder / files

and

- archive / files

When extracted, the first type ends up folder/files inside the **base folder** and the second ends up with only the files inside the **base folder**.

Because of this I choose **Extract each archive to separate folder** when mass extracting them.

The problem is that I end up with lots of **redundant folders** of the following kind: folder/folder/files.

I need a automated way to delete the that folder in the middle so that all of them end up in the following format: folder/files.

I'm using Windows 7. The archives are mostly RAR/ZIP with some being 7z, ACE.

Thank you.

PS: If there's a way to find out which archives have folders inside them and which do not would also be very useful.

Comment: My gosh, that happens to me so much.